# ffmpeg error > av_interleaved_write_frame(): No space left on device

Tags: ffmpeg

I am recording screen using ffmpeg with following command

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -f x11grab -i :0.0+0,0 -framerate 30 -crf 30 -video_size 400x400 output.mp4
```

When I have low memory on disk, ffmpeg throws `av_interleaved_write_frame(): No space left on device` error. And while opening recorded file getting error `This file contains no playable streams.`.

Is it possible to make the video file playable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with mp4, no. Mp4 requires the files be closed at the end to write out the moov box. This box containes information required to play the file, and is not possible to write out until the very end due to its structure. You can use a different container like mkv or flv that uses a different init structure and can be written and updated within the stream.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, yes. Recently I also ended up with a similar non-playable file due to low disk space. Try this free tool to fix it up:
https://www.videohelp.com/software/recover-mp4-to-h264

Usage:

```
recover_mp4.exe reference_file.mp4 --analyze
recover_mp4.exe broken.mp4 repaired.h264 [audio.aac | audio.wav | audio.mp3]
```